# Getting more tracks for 9V trains

Tags: trains, 9v

I own sets 4551 (Crocodile Locomotive) and 4583 (Load N' Haul Railroad). The rails are 9V conduction type with metal top.

How can I get additional rail to extend my line?

Can I use RC/PF rails and get the newer trains that do not need conduction from the rails??

Comment: I've 1 curved you can have, seen some on eBay £1-50 each months ago.

Answer (score 3):

LEGO doesn't make tracks that can conduct electricity anymore, so to get more you have three options:

1. 3rd party manufacturers - I know there are companies making curved track for larger curves than LEGO's own, I can't rule out that there's also companies making other types of track, but there's also copyright for them to think about
2. Used parts - curved track is cheap, straight tracks are expensive (most train sets came with a lot of curved track to make a circle, only some with a few straight tracks)
3. Make you own - as Ivan's answer details

Another solution is to buy some PF/PU trains motors etc., and rebuild the trains you have to use that, and drive them on plastic tracks. I guess you can find guides (for at least some models) online.

Comment: Thanx for prompt reply. Which 3rd party manufacturers? Will think about option 3. Any links to option 2??

Comment: I know some friends who are more into trains than I am have bought some of the mentioned curves, but I don't remember the companies names. For buying any kind of used LEGO, bricklink is probably the most used option, some people prefer brickowl. And then there's also auction sites like ebay, and local options (in Denmark we have something called "den blå avis" = "the blue newspaper"), flea markets/thrift stores/... - you might encounter sellers who doesn't know the market prices, that might both be good and bad.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is obtaining more tracks suitable for 9V lego trains, one option is to use copper foil tape to electrify currently available tracks.

[Chris Meyer wrote a lengthy article about this](https://chrismeyer.org/projects/lego-train-track/), so please read it. His results look encouraging:

[image: lego track and copper foil tape, unapplied]
[image: lego track and copper foil tape, applied]